# how to order data by most views category wise

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hii there this is little tricky question.Basically i am find for sql query or php code as may be comfortable for you ,so it is like i have i table named **post**.

So i ulitmately want that first of all from table it check most viewed post from each category then order it in category wise

TABLE ==> **post**

```
     content || category || views
    -------------------------------
     text 1   |  cat1    |  700
     text 2   |  cat2    | 2900  <==== most views in cat 2
     text 3   |  cat3    |  200
     text 4   |  cat1    | 1900  <==== most views in cat 1
     text 5   |  cat1    |  800
     text 6   |  cat2    |  800
     text 7   |  cat3    | 2700  <==== most views in cat 3
     text 8   |  cat2    |  900
     text 9   |  cat3    |  100
     text10   |  cat1    |  100
```

and my output coming as :

```
     content || category || views
   -------------------------------
     text 2   |  cat2    | 2900
     text 7   |  cat3    | 2700
     text 4   |  cat1    | 1900
```

And my desired output is :

```
     content || category || views
   -------------------------------
     text 2   |  cat2    | 2900
     text 8   |  cat2    | 900
     text 6   |  cat2    | 800
     text 7   |  cat3    | 2700
     text 3   |  cat3    | 200
     text 9   |  cat3    | 100
     text 4   |  cat1    | 1900     
     text 5   |  cat1    | 800 
     text 1   |  cat1    | 700   
     text 10  |  cat1    | 100
```

basically wanted to explode all the rows under each category but it is showing most viewed post in each category.

my query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM post t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT category, MAX(views) AS max_views
    FROM post
    GROUP BY category
) t2
    ON t1.category = t2.category AND t1.views = t2.max_views;
```

i want to to show all other rows under each category.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM post t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT category, MAX(views) AS max_views
    FROM post
    GROUP BY category
) t2
    ON t1.category = t2.category
ORDER BY
    t2.max_views,
    t1.category,
    t1.views;
```

Note also that I removed the `t1.views = t2.max_views` condition from the join.  In this case, you want every original row returned.

Comment: @tarun you might want to accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want an `order by`:

```
select p.*
from post p
order by (select max(p2.views) from post p2 where p2.category = p.category) desc,
         p.category,
         p.views desc;
```

You can also do this with your `group by`:

```
select p.*
from post p join
     (select p2.category, max(p2.views) as max_views
      from post p2
      group by p2.category
     ) p2
     on p2.category = p.category
order by p2.max_views desc, p.category, p.views desc;
```

Note that the `order by` has three keys.  The middle key, `p.category`, handles the case when two categories have the same number of maximum views.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for the subselect. You did not specify the order of the category themselves:

```
select    content, category, views
from      post
order by  category, views desc
```

Unless you really want the categories to change position based on the max views of their most popular posts, you should avoid the subselect for a faster retrieval. Of course given your indexes are set properly.